# knitr: Create environment to share variables across chunks which are deleted when finished

Tags: r, knitr, environment

I'm developing an R package (https://github.com/rcst/rmaxima) that provides an interface to the computer algebra system Maxima. I want to include a knitr engine, so that it can directly be used with knitr. The package has functions to start/ spawn a child process and then send commands to and fetch results from Maxima. This way, it should be possible to carry over results between different chunks.

The interface works by creating a new object of an Rcpp-class of the interface. Creating the object spawns a child process, deleting the objects stops that process.

I want the engine to start a new child process each time the document is `knit()`ed, so that the result is reproducible. I'm thinking that I could create an extra environment that binds the interface object. The engine checks whether this objects exists in that environment. If it doesn't exist, it will be created, otherwise the engine can directly proceed to send code to the interface. When `knit()` exits, it exits the scope of it's environment and all variables within that environment are deleted automatically. This way, I need not stop the child process, because the object of the interface class get's deleted and the process is stopped automatically.

But I have no clue how to go about it. Any hints very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yihui provides an answer [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1977).

In essence, (a) one sets a temporary variable in the parent frame to check if the engine is running and (b) inspects the lists of chunk labels to determine if the current one is the last and therefore trigger deletion and tear down after it's been processed:

```r
 last_label <- function(label = knitr::opts_current$get('label')) {
  if (knitr:::child_mode()) return(FALSE)
  labels <- names(knitr::knit_code$get())
  tail(labels, 1) == label
}

knitr::knit_engines$set(maxima = local({
  mx <- FALSE
  function(options) {
    if (!mx) {
      maxima$startMaxima()
      mx <<- TRUE
    }
    
    ...  # run maxima code
    
    if (last_label(options$label)) {
      maxima$stopMaxima()
      mx <<- FALSE
    }
  }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I also came up with a solution which works, but is less robust.

Objects that go out of scope are automatically removed in R. However, actual deletion happens during R's garbage collection `gc()`, which cannot be controlled directly. So to get an object removed when `knit()` finishes, that object needs to be created in the environment of `knit()`, which is some levels above the engine call.

In principle one can register a function that does the actual clean-up via `on.exit()` of `knit()`, who's environment can be retrieved by `parent.frame(n=...)`. Note that all objects of that scope are still present the moment the expressions registered to `on.exit()` get called.

```r
 maxima.engine <- function(options) { 
    e <- parent.frame(n = sys.parent() - 2)
    if(!exists("mx", envir = e)) {
        message("starting maxima on first chunk")
        assign(x = "mx", value = new(rmaxima:::RMaxima), envir = e)
        assign(x = "execute", value = get("mx", envir = e)$execute, envir = e)
        assign(x = "stopMaxima", value = get("mx", envir = e)$stopMaxima, envir = e)

        # quit maxima "on.exit"ing of knit()
        # eval() doesn't work on "special primitive functions
        # do.call() does ... this may break in the future
        # see https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-November/067874.html
        do.call("on.exit", list(quote(stopMaxima()), 
                    add = TRUE), envir = e)
    }

    code <- options$code
    out <- character(0);
    for(i in 1:length(code))
        out <- c(out, eval(call("execute", code[i]), envir = e))

    engine_output(options, code, out)
}
```